# EWS Managed API 2, setting FlagStatus

Tags: exchange-server, ews-managed-api

I'm attempting to set the Flag on an e-mail using EWS Managed API 2 - however, I keep getting an error that I can't seem to get past.

I'm doing the following:

```
ExchangeService exchangeService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);   
exchangeService.Url = new Uri(<ews url comes from Outlook JavaScript API>);
exchangeService.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
exchangeService.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(<ews token comes from Outlook JavaScript API>);
```

And then a little later:

```
Item item = Item.Bind(exchangeService, new ItemId(<mail id comes from Outlook JavaScript API>), new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Flag));
item.Load();
item.Flag = new Flag() { FlagStatus = ItemFlagStatus.Flagged }; 
item.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve);
```

What am I missing?

I keep getting this error:

> You must load or assign this property before you can read its value.

**UPDATE:** Ok, it turned out the this error was caused by some other code which has been corrected.

Now I'm getting this error instead:

> The requested web method is unavailable to this caller or application.